# Pythonic way to determine if json object contains a certain value?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a json object I get returned from a call, similar to this:

```
{
    'Tags': [
        {
            'Key': 'Dept',
            'PropagateAtLaunch': True,
            'ResourceId': 'my-auto-scaling-group',
            'ResourceType': 'auto-scaling-group',
            'Value': 'Research',
        },
        {
            'Key': 'Role',
            'PropagateAtLaunch': True,
            'ResourceId': 'my-auto-scaling-group',
            'ResourceType': 'auto-scaling-group',
            'Value': 'WebServer',
        },
        {
            'Key': 'ecs_scaling',
            'PropagateAtLaunch': True,
            'ResourceId': 'my-auto-scaling-group',
            'ResourceType': 'auto-scaling-group',
            'Value': 'true',
        },
    ],
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        '...': '...',
    },
}
```

Is there a more Pythonic way of simply determining whether or not the Key `ecs_scaling` exists, other than the standard:

```
data = json.loads(theThing)
for key in data.items():
   ...
```

The Key could be the first item, it could be the 40th item -- ideally I'd like to be able to do something like `if 'ecs_scaling' in theKeys: ...` ?

Comment: Will 'ecs_scaling' always be in a Tags key? And will Tags always exist?

Comment: `ecs_scaling` may or may not exist, `Tags` will always be in the response.

Comment: Because `Tags` contains a list, all solutions are going to iterate the list in linear time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the builtin [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any).

> [Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return False.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)

```
if any(tag['key'] == 'ecs_scaling' for tag in data['Tags']):
    ...
```

Comment: Same complexity that "for key in data.items():"

Comment: @Xire: I believe `tag['key'] == 'ecs_scaling'` would be faster than `'ecs_scaling' in tag.items()`, as there is not guarantee than the `key` item will be the first element of `tag.items()` (you may end up iterating over additional items), as opposed to selecting the appropriate key. Edit: If you're referring to Right Leg's approach, that seems like it would be slower, to me.

Answer (score 3):

The complexity is already linear, so the only faster thing that you could hope for is a hash search.
However, constructing a hash set or a hash table would require a linear complexity.

So unless the functions you call from the `json` module already build such a hash set, an iteration is the best thing you can do, for a linear complexity, ie `O(n)`.

In this regard, I think the most Pythonic approach is using the `any` built-in, already mentioned by the other.

For the sake of completeness, although it would be less performant, you could go with a list comprehension as well, which is often considered as "highly Pythonic":

```
'ecs_scaling' in [item['Key'] for item in data.items()]
```

This is not as good, because an additional list has to be constructed, which requires an iteration over the whole data.

Comment: Set comp would be more suitable so you don't have the O(n) lookup.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Sure thing, but the set needs to be built... However, it might be (although I doubt it) that the `json` module already provides such lookup functions, so that *in effect* no additional processing is required...

Comment: If the first key you check is `'ecs_scaling'`, you wouldn't need to access the rest of them. You're building an array of *all* keys, but may only need the first one/two/etc.

Comment: @ZachGates Yes, that's one of my points. I forgot to add "for the sake of completeness"...

Answer (score 2):

```
any(el['Key'] == 'ecs_scaling' for el in data['Tags'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking if there could be another way of doing that. Though it's little funny ;) but it will work and reduce calling any `build-in` methods for this. However I doubt if I am fulfilling the criteria of doing it in pythonic way.

However I am definitely considering the fact that the `Key` and its value `ecs_scaling` will exist in the desired data section i.e `Tags`. Along with that the patterns should be fixed otherwise the solution wont work i.e `"Key": "ecs_scaling"` that I think will be if it was a dict before came here as string.

Simply use the `str.find` but you may need to call this twice to ensure desirable result.
`if data.find("'Key': 'ecs_scaling'") != -1 or data.find('"Key": "ecs_scaling"') != -1`

But yes `any` is one of the best solutions if we ignore shortfalls of not checking if-exist prior to checking entire dataset.